# How can I show JQuery effects at same time?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate

I use below code but it's not working synchronic, how can I do it?

```
$(".Bio").click(function(){
     $(".BioText p").delay(2000).fadeIn(600).animate({margin:"0 0 0 0"},600,'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working synchronic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".Bio").click(function(){
     $(".BioText p").delay(2000).animate({margin:"0 0 0 0", opacity:1},600,'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

This will animate both the opacity and margin together. Creating the desired fade in effect. Just make sure that in your CSS:

```
.BioText p{
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to [Yotam Omer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25974639/2324107), you can use the `(properties[, options])` way of writting `.animate`. In the option object, you can turn the `queue` to false :

```
$(".Bio").click(function(){
     $(".BioText p").delay(2000)
     .fadeIn(600)
     .animate({margin:"0 0 0 0"}, {
         duration : 600,
         easing : 'easeInOutExpo',
         queue : false
     });
});
```

> ## queue (default: true)
>
> *Type: Boolean or String*
>
> A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string. When a custom queue name is used the animation does not automatically start; you must call .dequeue("queuename") to start it.